# Tell pkg-config to look *.pc files also in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig, system-wide

Tags: configuration, environment-variables

Right now `pkg-config` looks only in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`. I can adjust it for a user by exporting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable, but once again I forgot to do it for root and wasted time wondering, why my plugin is not installed properly (the makefile used `pkg-config`). So how can set it system wide, so it would always look in to both `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: I find it slightly ridiculous that a system-wide tool like `pkg-config` doesn't have a config file..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional place to define an environment variable system-wide is `/etc/profile`. This file is read by Bourne-style shells (including bash, ksh, ash) when you log in for a text-mode session, either locally (on a text mode console) or remotely (over ssh). If you log in in a graphical environment, `/etc/profile` may or may not be read, depending on your login manager, desktop environment and operating system distribution.

A better method, if available on your system, is to define the environment variable in `/etc/environment`. This file is read by [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules), specifically by the [`pam_env` module](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html). These variables are available in all sessions started by a login method that uses PAM and has the `pam_env` module referenced in `/etc/pam.conf` or `/etc/pam.d/$method`.

Answer (score -2):

Probably the easiest, although not 100% reliable way would be to add it to `/etc/bashrc`.

It's not reliable because any individual user can set to not process `/etc/bashrc`.

If you want to go the more complex way, you can create a wrapper that will set it. First you rename `pkg-config` to `pkg-config-real`, then make a new script named `pkg-config` that will set the variable.

(As root, or use sudo)

```
cd /usr/bin
mv pkg-config pkg-config-real
```

Then make a new file in /usr/bin/pkg-config with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
pkg-config-real $*
```

Be sure to make it executable.

```
chmod 755 pkg-config
```

Comment: `/etc/bashrc` isn't the right place, see [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/183980#183980). You should not recommend modifying a file in `/usr/bin`; it would be better to create `/usr/local/bin/pkg-config` and call `/usr/bin/pkg-config` from there. In your script, you must use `"$@"`, not `$*`; further improvements: `#!/bin/sh` and `exec pkg-config-real`.